# How to write a custom function in a model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model class I have created with Devise.

I have a role field (admin=0, user=1) in my model.

Screenshot of my database:

[image: Screenshot of my database]

### HTML View

```
<% if current_user.active_admin? %>
  <%= render 'layouts/admin' %>   
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/user' %>
<% end %>
```

### Model

```
def active_admin?
   #your logic here
end
```

I want to login. If I am an admin check role is 0 render to layouts/admin else I am a user check role is 1 render to layouts/user.

How do I write code in the model to do this?

Comment: are u using an enum for role field?

Comment: Is your `role` field an Rails enum or boolean datatype?

Answer (score 3):

In your user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_admin?
    role == 0
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<% if current_user.active_admin? %>
  <%= render 'layouts/admin' %>   
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/user' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can see right one but I could not get  the point of adding method in model for one-liner code. You could check it as `current_user.role?` which returns false for 0. Perhaps you are going to call current_user method to call active_admin?

Answer (score 2):

As Mark says, you can just check `role` for 0 or 1.

Any column in your database will map directly to a method on the model.

A couple of points:

- If you're using Rails 5 you'll need to inherit from `ApplicationRecord` rather than `ActiveRecord::Base`.
- In newer versions of Ruby you can use the `#zero?` method:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def active_admin?
    role.zero?
  end
end
```

Comment: This is probably nicer than mine to be fair

Answer (score 1):

No need of adding a method for checking the roles, you can directly achieve this by below change. It will return true for anything other than 0.

```
<% if current_user.role? %>
  <%= render 'layouts/user' %>        
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/admin' %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way can be add an method on application controller as

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if current_user.role==0
      #your admin path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end


  def authenticate_admin
    unless (user_signed_in? and current_user.role !=0 )
      redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
    end
  end
```

add to the required controller

```
  before_filter :authenticate_admin
  layout 'admin'
```